# onClick() works on the first click only - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I am trying to make onClick() function work for every button (its the same result), but as of now onClick() works only once.

If I click on a button again (the same or different) the pop up doesn't work anymore.

Could you please help? I cannot figure out how to fix it.

```js
function Challange() {
  const [isPopped, setPop] = useState(false);

  const pop = () => {
    setPop(true);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {isPopped && <Dialog2 />}
      <div className="challanges">
        <h1 className="newchallenge">Choose New Challange</h1>
        <button className="challangeBtn" onClick={pop}>
          Eat Vegetarian (31days)
        </button>
        <button className="challangeBtn" onClick={pop}>
          Take the bike to work (14days)
        </button>
        <button className="challangeBtn" onClick={pop}>
          Recycle your plastic bottles (31days)
        </button>
        <button className="challangeBtn" onClick={pop}>
          Use public transport to commute (31days)
        </button>
        <button className="challangeBtn" onClick={pop}>
          Don't fly an airplane (365days)
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Challange;
```

Comment: Do you ever call `setPop(false)`? In the code you've provided it only happens one way, so once it's set to true it remains true forever, and thus any subsequent clicks don't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your pop function code only sets the state to true, so it will never be false again. You may change it like this.

```
const pop = () => {
        setPop(!isPopped);
      };
```

Comment: Thank you! this works! The only problem is that now I need to click on the button twice to get the response! Any idea why?

Comment: I need to see other parts of the code to answer this, could be related to other hooks.

Comment: the issue is the popped state is shared by all the buttons so if you click one it changes the state for every button... console log isPopped and youll see what im talking about

Comment: Is there any way to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

in your case `setPop` can take boolean value OR method that returns boolean.
Best practices for handle toggling in React looks like:

```
const pop = () => {
   setPop(currentValue => !currentValue);
};
```

Also, use `useCallback` hook to manage events like click and avoid re-initialization of your method on each render:

```
const pop = useCallback(() => {
   setPop(currentValue => !currentValue);
}, []);
```

Comment: the issue she's having is that each button shares the same state, that is why she believes she needs to click twice for the desired result.  each button needs to have its own state