# onClick() works only on second-click - react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My buttons only work after I double click on them.

I learned in the previous post that the issue is that the popped state is shared by all the buttons so if you click one it changes the state for every button

Can anyone please help me to find a solution?

```js
function Challange() {
  const [isPopped, setPop] = useState(false);

  const pop = () => {
    setPop(!isPopped);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {isPopped && <Dialog2 />}
      <div className="challanges">
        <h1 className="newchallenge">Choose New Challange</h1>
        <button className="challangeBtn" onClick={pop}>
          Eat Vegetarian (31days)
        </button>
        <button className="challangeBtn" onClick={pop}>
          Take the bike to work (14days)
        </button>
        <button className="challangeBtn" onClick={pop}>
          Recycle your plastic bottles (31days)
        </button>
        <button className="challangeBtn" onClick={pop}>
          Use public transport to commute (31days)
        </button>
        <button className="challangeBtn" onClick={pop}>
          Don't fly an airplane (365days)
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Challange;
```

Comment: I mean, if you have 2 states alternately, and your function fires at only one, therefore it needs to be double clicked.

Comment: I don't see any problem here. I have added a reproducible code to your post. You can try it. Or may be add Dialog component as well. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-q7h8r?file=/Challange.jsx

Comment: Seems to be working for me. Check out https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-gareth-2ftkc

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that your pop function is implemented like a `toggle`. It will switch from true to false and from false to true.

Like @otacilio said, just change it to true.

What probably is happening is this: Your first click opens the Dialog, then you close the dialog but dont set `isPopped`to false again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open the dialog when you click the button, you can change the pop function to set the state to true making it like:

```
const pop = () => {
    setPop(true);
};
```

Your current code will switch the state every time you click the button, so at the first click your Dialog2 will be rendered, and at your second click will be hidden again.

PS:

I saw your [last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64936603/onclick-works-on-the-first-click-only-react) and I think what you want is a way to open your dialog and a way to close your dialog.

So you can make something like:

```
function Challange() {
  const [isPopped, setPop] = useState(false);

  const openDialog = () => {
    setPop(true);
  };
  
  // renember to call this function when you want to close the dialog
  const closeDialog = () => {
    setPop(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {isPopped && <Dialog2 />}
      <div className="challanges">
        <h1 className="newchallenge">Choose New Challange</h1>
        <button className="challangeBtn" onClick={openDialog}>
          Eat Vegetarian (31days)
        </button>
        <button className="challangeBtn" onClick={openDialog}>
          Take the bike to work (14days)
        </button>
        <button className="challangeBtn" onClick={openDialog}>
          Recycle your plastic bottles (31days)
        </button>
        <button className="challangeBtn" onClick={openDialog}>
          Use public transport to commute (31days)
        </button>
        <button className="challangeBtn" onClick={openDialog}>
          Don't fly an airplane (365days)
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Challange;
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing your pop function to **true** where setPop is called, will make sure the function works on the first onClick, rather than it being toggled to what you want on the second click.

```
const pop = () => {
setPop(true); 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manage the state for each type of challenge and toggle the PopUp only when one challenge is selected. I presume only one single challenge can be select at a time.

```js
class Challenge extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isPopped: false,
            selectedChallenge: ""
        }
    }

    selectChallenge = (challengeName) => {
        this.setState({
            selectedChallenge: challengeName,
        });
        this.togglePopped();
    }

    togglePopped = () => {
        this.setState({isPopped: !this.state.isPopped});
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            {this.state.isPopped && <Dialog2 challenge={this.state.selectedChallenge} hideDialog={this.togglePopped}/>}

            <div className="challanges">
                <h1 className="newchallenge">Choose New Challange</h1>
                <button className="challangeBtn" onClick={() => {
                    this.selectChallenge('Eat Vegetarian (31days ')
                }}>
                    Eat Vegetarian (31days)
                </button>
                <button className="challangeBtn" onClick={() => {
                    this.selectChallenge('Take the bike to work (14days)')
                }}>
                    Take the bike to work (14days)
                </button>
                <button className="challangeBtn" onClick={() => {
                    this.selectChallenge('Recycle your plastic bottles (31days)')
                }}>
                    Recycle your plastic bottles (31days)
                </button>
                <button className="challangeBtn" onClick={() => {
                    this.selectChallenge('Use public transport to commute (31days)')
                }}>
                    Use public transport to commute (31days)
                </button>
                <button className="challangeBtn" onClick={() => {
                    this.selectChallenge("Don't fly an airplane (365days)")
                }}>
                    Don't fly an airplane (365days)
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>;
    }
}

class Dialog2 extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return <div class="dialog">
            <h2>Dialog2</h2>
            <div>{this.props.challenge}</div>
            <button onClick={this.props.hideDialog}>Hide</button>
        </div>
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Challenge/>, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

```css
.dialog {
  width: 500px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Here is the functional component version

```
function Challenge (props) {
    const [isPopped, setIsPopped] = useState(false);
    const [selectedChallenge, setSelectedChallenge] = useState("");

    const selectChallenge = (challengeName) => {
        setSelectedChallenge(challengeName);
        togglePopped();
    }

    const togglePopped = () => {
        setIsPopped(!isPopped);
    }

    return <div>
        {isPopped && <Dialog2 challenge={selectedChallenge} hideDialog={togglePopped}/>}

        <div className="challanges">
            <h1 className="newchallenge">Choose New Challange</h1>
            <button className="challangeBtn" onClick={() => {
                selectChallenge('Eat Vegetarian (31days ')
            }}>
                Eat Vegetarian (31days)
            </button>
            <button className="challangeBtn" onClick={() => {
                selectChallenge('Take the bike to work (14days)')
            }}>
                Take the bike to work (14days)
            </button>
            <button className="challangeBtn" onClick={() => {
                selectChallenge('Recycle your plastic bottles (31days)')
            }}>
                Recycle your plastic bottles (31days)
            </button>
            <button className="challangeBtn" onClick={() => {
                selectChallenge('Use public transport to commute (31days)')
            }}>     
                Use public transport to commute (31days)
            </button>
            <button className="challangeBtn" onClick={() => {
                selectChallenge("Don't fly an airplane (365days)")
            }}> 
                Don't fly an airplane (365days)
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>;
}

function Dialog2() {
    return <div>
        <h2>Dialog2</h2>
        <div>{props.challenge}</div>
        <button onClick={props.hideDialog}>Hide</button>
    </div>
}
```